# Building SDL2_image as a CMake external project

Tags: cmake, sdl-2, sdl-image

I've been trying to create a CMake-based build-system for a project that is supposed to use SDL2_image library. I do not want to force user to install any libraries to the system to be able to build the project, so I took advantage of the CMake's ability to download and build dependencies (freetype, SDL2 and SDL2_image) from source code as External Projects.

Everything is fine with freetype and SDL2 (which both include *CMakeLists.txt* files out of the box), but I've ran out of ideas how to make it work for SDL2_image. CMake's external projects support custom configuration and building settings which I used in different variants with no success.

The CMake file itself can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/SergNikitin/d8d9441120d00459201d), but the problematic part is this:

```
# SDL_image library
ExternalProject_Add(sdl2_image_project
    URL https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.0.tar.gz
    DEPENDS sdl2_project
    PREFIX ${LIBS_DIR}/SDL2_image
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND LDFLAGS=-L${SDL2_BIN} CFLAGS=-I${SDL2_SRC}/include SDL2_CONFIG=${SDL2_BIN}/sdl2-config <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR> --enable-shared=no
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

An [error](https://gist.github.com/SergNikitin/458e625f0808a9f8daee) occurs while building **sdl2_image_project**. Some trivial research discovered that the error is generated by the undefined references to parts of **libdl**. Here is a tiny part of the hole error:

```
libtool: link: gcc -I/home/snikitin/_src/img_glypher/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT -o showimage showimage.o -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -pthread  -L/home/snikitin/_src/img_glypher/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build ./.libs/libSDL2_image.a -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -pthread
/home/snikitin/_src/img_glypher/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/libSDL2.a(SDL_dynapi.c.o): In function `get_sdlapi_entry':
/home/snikitin/_src/img_glypher/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project/src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi.c:227: undefined reference to `dlopen'
```

I think the problem takes place due to the fact that linker tries to create a shared version of SDL2_image library while linking it to a static **libSDL2.a**. The thing is - if this is right - SDL2 building step creates both static and shared versions of itself so one would assume that linker would use **libSDL2-2.0.so** instead (I do not actually need a shared library - just the static one, but I do not know how to prevent the build system from trying to create it apart from passing `--enable-shared=no` to SDL2_image configure script, which does not help in this case).

After a lot of googling I've discovered that the possible source of the problem is that `sdl2-config` (which is called to get some flags for compiler during SDL_image building) may be called with wrong arguments and produces wrong cflags which confuse everything else. But I'm not sure that is the case and also I do not know how to influence `sdl2_config` call from CMake (`configure --help` does not seem to unveil any useful options for this situation).

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 if it matters in any way. Would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to link some libraries like `m` and `dl`. It can be fixed by providing
custom `sdl2-config` file. Copy `sdl2-config` from extracted archive and substitute `--libs` result:

```
--libs)
  echo -L${exec_prefix}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${libdir} -pthread -lSDL2 -lm -ldl
  ;;
```

Note that order is important (that's why just modifying LIBS not works for me).
Now this file can be used in your `ExternalProject_Add` command instead of `SDL2_CONFIG=${SDL2_BIN}/sdl2-config`:

```
...
... CFLAGS=-I${SDL2_SRC}/include SDL2_CONFIG=${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/sdl2-config <SOURCE_DIR>/configure
...
```

Comment: It worked! Not much room for automated build though :(